# Compare the data of two arrays using foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, comparison

I'm currently trying to compare the data of two arrays against eachother. My code looks something like the one below:

```
foreach ($arrayOne as $one) {
    $variable = $one['one'];
    foreach ($arrayTwo as $two) {
        if ($two == $variable) { 
            echo "Match!";
        }
    }
}
```

However, it only compares against the first element in `$arrayTwo`, it's not looping through everything `$arrayTwo`. Why is this? Furthermore, is there a MORE EFFICIENT way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

SNIPPET of Array One:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'paper_item_id' => 1,
    'type' => 1,
    'cost' => 20,
    'is_member' => false,
    'label' => 'Blue',
    'prompt' => 'Blue',
    'layer' => 1500,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'paper_item_id' => 2,
    'type' => 1,
    'cost' => 20,
    'is_member' => false,
    'label' => 'Green',
    'prompt' => 'Green',
    'layer' => 1500,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'paper_item_id' => 3,
    'type' => 1,
    'cost' => 20,
    'is_member' => false,
    'label' => 'Pink',
    'prompt' => 'Pink',
    'layer' => 1500,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'paper_item_id' => 4,
    'type' => 1,
    'cost' => 20,
    'is_member' => false,
    'label' => 'Black',
    'prompt' => 'Black',
    'layer' => 1500,
  ),
)
```

SNIPPET of Array Two:

```
array (
  0 => 'Blue',
  1 => '
Purple Bat Wings',
  2 => '
Black Motorbike',
  3 => '
Test Scarf',
  4 => '
Black',
  5 => '
Green',
  6 => '
Referee Jersey',
  7 => '
Stethoscope',
  8 => '
Custom Hoodie',
  9 => '
',
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like $var2 = $two['two'] and then you compare it with the $variable in the if statement. Please show us your full code. Thanks

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/xoL6BO It prints `Match` for the first and third elements in `$arrayTwo`.

Comment: @AliGajani The code is comparing all of the elements of $arrayTwo against all of the "one" elements in $arrayOne. $arrayOne is the result of `json_decode()` while $arrayTwo is the result of a normal `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to make an associative array from the `$arrayOne` values:

```
$check = array();
foreach ($arrayOne as $one) {
    $check[$one['one']] = true;
}
foreach ($arrayTwo as $two) {
    if (isset($check[$two])) {
        echo 'Match! <br/>';
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ezRobm)

The actual problem in the original code is that the `explode()` code is returning an array where each element in `$arrayTwo` begins with a newline, except the first one. But the corresponding values in `$arrayOne` don't have newlines, so they don't match. You need to fix the `explode()` code, which isn't shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks! However, this is still giving me the same result. It stops after the first match, even though there are a lot more.

Comment: Can you add output of `var_export($arrayOne); var_export($arrayTwo);` to your question. Maybe the problem is that the arrays aren't laid out the way you expect.

Comment: There's no `one` key in `$arrayOne`.

Comment: I apologize, the `one` was just used as a test, in my actual code the `one` is `label`.

Comment: That output looks like `print_r`, not `var_export`. I can't cut and paste it into my demo.

Comment: I apologize, I have just added in the output from `var_export`.

Comment: That helps a lot. There are newlines in all the `$arrayTwo` elements except the first one. That's why none of the other ones match.

Comment: You should trim them, or fix the `explode` code so it doesn't leave newlines.

Answer (score 1):

The `array_diff` (or `array_diff_assoc` in your case) function returns the values that differs in two (or more) arrays. If return value is empty, they don't differ at all.

Comment: Neither these functions can be used with these arrays, because he's comparing top-level elements of `$arrayTwo` with values 2-level deep in `$arrayOne`.